# How to pass wildcard into nginx proxy host header?

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx server defined (lots of irrelevant parts removed):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;

    location ~ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
        proxy_set_header Host localhost;
    }
}
```

It works fine when you go to `mydomain.com`. The host header gets set as `localhost` as I expect.

What I want now is when you go to `test.mydomain.com` to have the host header be `test.localhost` or when you go to `random.mydomain.com` to have the host header be `random.localhost`.

Basically taking that wildcard `*` and putting it at the beginning of the host header. Or have it default to `localhost` (without any prefix) if it uses `mydomain.com`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: something like `server_name     ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.mydomain\.com$;` and use `subdomain` variable to set header `proxy_set_header Host $subdomain.localhost`

Comment: @JackSparrow That doesn't work. When you go to `mydomain.com` the host gets set as `.localhost` instead of `localhost`.